# Force Bootstrap 3 table header to fixed widths

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, styling

I need to fix the width of the header columns in my [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/) table, regardless of the content in the regular rows. This is to avoid content being separated onto two lines as you can see below, which looks awfully untidy:
[image: Broken table headers]

Is there any way to do this, preferably without toying with the padding for every table row as I'm happy with the current spacing. You can see the full table at http://find-minecraft-servers.com/, and I've included the HTML, and custom CSS associated with the table below. The content for the table is generated by PHP, so the length of the values in each table cell is subject to change.

```
<table class="table bigtable" width="100%;">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-list-ol"></i> RANK</th>
          <th class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> NAME</th>
          <th class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-server"></i> SERVER</th>
          <th class="text-center">
            <a href="?sort=votes" style="text-decoration:none;color:#fff;">
              <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> VOTES <i class="fa fa-sort" style="color:#84fb88;"></i>
            </a>
          </th>
          <th class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> STATUS</th>
          <th class="text-center">
            <a href="?sort=players" style="text-decoration:none;color:#fff;">
              <i class="fa fa-users"></i> PLAYERS <i class="fa fa-sort" style="color:#84fb88;"></i>
            </a>
          </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      CONTENT...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Custom.css:

```
.bigtable thead {
    background-color: #12bbb9;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.bigtable thead tr th {
    padding:8px 5px 8px 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `table-layout:fixed` to the `table`, then give `width` to the `th` containing the large image.

```
.table {
       margin-bottom: 20px;
       max-width: 100%;
       table-layout: fixed; /*newly added*/
       width: 100%;
    }
```